OpenShift Pods failing to be deleted when Job is deleted
On OpenShift V4.12 the cronjob 'collect-profiles' within the namespace 'openshift-operator-lifecycle-manager' starts a job every 15 minutes. The cronjob has a setting of
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 3
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1

Thus 3 jobs are kept, and the oldest fourth job is deleted as specified. However, the associated pod of the fourth job is not being deleted when the job is deleted (which should be the default action). The job/pod completes successfully, so its not a case of keeping an error or the like.
I have not been able to find a global/cluster setting that could change this action, but could be missing something.
Although the job has completed, and so the pod is marked completed and not using any resources, having large numbers of pods makes any debug etc work troublesome. I have a script that helps clean up, but would like to get to the bottom of this issue.
